# How to detect a unique person in front of media station

Tags: actionscript-3, air

i need to create an application that is capable of detecting a person entering and leaving the area in front of a big screen.
since sensors like infrared and ultrasound can easily be fooled by multiple persons i was thinking of using face / person recognition.
one option would be to use the kinekt sensor.
my questions: is this system reliable? is there another good option?

Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already used kinect for this kind of projects in actionscript and unity with c# and i can say that's your best and only solution to detect person and mantain a low cost. 
You have 2 possibilities to use kinect with as3:

- First is to use AIR with a ANE (adobe native extension) and interface c++/c# dll with your application.
- Second one is to use the old trick of the socket communication. You have 2 application as3 and c#/c++ and you put them in communication with a tcp/udp connection on the loopback interface.

IMHO the best solution is the first one, you don't have to write a good protocol to communicate but you just call methods and receive events as a normal API.